# Refresh html frames for cross-domain sites out of my control

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

This may be a bit of an x y problem, so I'll give a small bit of background to start with. I am attempting to make a simple dashboard which loads a number of different sites and which cycles between them. To do this I have set up a simple local server along with a html page which gets populated with the different sites in distict frames and then cycles between them by hiding/showing each one in turn. In simple terms, the page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame1" src="www.example1.com"> </iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" src="www.example2.com"> </iframe>
<iframe id="frame3" src="www.example2.com"> </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, what I would like to do is be able to force a reload of each frame so that the data is up to date. For most sites I can do this with:

```
document.getElementById['iframe.src'] = document.getElementById['iframe.src']
```

However, for sites where content changes aren't reflected in the URL, this won't work and will instead 'refresh' the page back to the home page. What I want to do is esentially submit an F5 sort of refresh direct to the frame or use:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

or

```
document.getElementById('YOUR IFRAME').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

But, due to CORS, I can't do this. Considering the sites are external sites that I am viewing and have no control over I'm struggling to come up with a way to get around this issue. Is there something pretty obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything, that's how the web works. You have no control over a page from another domain, except if you use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) but thas implies the target page acknowledges your messages and reacts accordingly.

In other terms, you won't achieve this unless you have control over the pages you are embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try and tell the page in the iframe to reload, which you will be blocked from doing. You could instead update the URL in the iframe tag, by adding some random crap to the end of the URL

So for example `news.bbc.co.uk` would become `news.bbc.co.uk?qaz=1`, then change this each time you want it to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like time by removing iframe element & creating again at same place,

this will seems like same page is being refreshed.

working example : this will refresh the frame every 5 second.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="frameContainer1">
        <iframe id="frame1" width="500" height="500" src="http://www.example.com"> </iframe>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        setInterval(function(){
            let elem = document.getElementById('frameContainer1');
            var elemFrame = document.getElementById('frame1');
            elem.removeChild(elemFrame);
            var newFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
            newFrame.id = 'frame1';
            newFrame.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.com');
            newFrame.width = 500;
            newFrame.height = 500;
            elem.appendChild(newFrame);
        },5000)
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```